Unable to select multiple files on File Upload Dialog
In order to report a problem with Firefox I needed to upload screenshots demonstrating the expected behaviour and what I observed to bugzilla.  I tried to upload the two screenshots but the File Upload dialog refused to permit me to select the two files.  Even if I was holding down the shift button, when I selected one of the files, the other file became unselected.  This is on Ubuntu 23.10.
What do I have to do to get this tool to permit me to select multiple files?

It might be that the website only allows single file upload.
